# Cucumber-js TypeError: e.scrollIntoView is not a function

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

I got the same exception on trying to setup cucumber-js https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js

Feature: Example feature

As a user of Cucumber.js I want to have documentation on Cucumber So that I can concentrate on building awesome applications

Scenario: Reading documentation # features\my_featue.feature:8 Given I am on the Cucumber.js GitHub repository # features\step_definitions\my_step_definitions.js:4 TypeError: e.scrollIntoView is not a function at n (https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github-30a28ef79b52e130ca6c7a146955fad76599bfdde471ee6896f356fb1ae94a56.js:2:10072) at Object.r [as scrollToFragmentTarget] (https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github-30a28ef79b52e130ca6c7a146955fad76599bfdde471ee6896f356fb1ae94a56.js:2:10169) at https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github-30a28ef79b52e130ca6c7a146955fad76599bfdde471ee6896f356fb1ae94a56.js:2:10882 at r (https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-bebe77cf3c6ad6033e7df85a57952b158d1d0fadbe3590af19a960b00413bbec.js:6:16866) at https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-bebe77cf3c6ad6033e7df85a57952b158d1d0fadbe3590af19a960b00413bbec.js:6:16231 at s (https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-bebe77cf3c6ad6033e7df85a57952b158d1d0fadbe3590af19a960b00413bbec.js:6:15888) at HTMLDocument.a (https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-bebe77cf3c6ad6033e7df85a57952b158d1d0fadbe3590af19a960b00413bbec.js:6:15916) at callListeners (C:\Users\mayank.arora\Documents\tutorials\112_NodeJS\Cucumber\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\events\EventTarget.js:170:34) at dispatchPhase (C:\Users\mayank.arora\Documents\tutorials\112_NodeJS\Cucumber\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\events\EventTarget.js:159:7) at HTMLDocument.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\mayank.arora\Documents\tutorials\112_NodeJS\Cucumber\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\events\EventTarget.js:115:3) in https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js When I go to the README file # features\step_definitions\my_step_definitions.js:15 Then I should see "Usage" as the page title # features\step_definitions\my_step_definitions.js:22

Failing scenarios: features\my_featue.feature:8 # Scenario: Reading documentation

1 scenario (1 failed) 3 steps (1 failed, 2 skipped) 0m02.003s

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I tried the example at: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js on Windows 7 Enterprize, 64 bit.

Comment: what does your package.json look like? it seems like you have some corrupted dependency that you probably do not need

Comment: @nilesh I'm having the same problem on Node 4.1.2 on a OS X. I've created a sample repo that merely attempts to get the example code running. https://github.com/pmcelhaney/cucumber-test

Comment: Link to the same issue on the Cucumber repo: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/526